# How can I sum values from a getter method within an iterator?

Tags: java, oop, iterator, sum

I'm trying to sum numerical values from a getter method (drawing values from an ArrayList) using an iterator.

Function in question:

```
public void overallTotal()
{
    Iterator<Customer> customers = model.getCustomerIterator();
    while (customers.hasNext())
    {
        Customer customer = customers.next();
        int sum = 0;
        sum = customer.getTotalForAllOrders() + sum;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

for an interface `model`.

This is simply printing getTotalForAllOrders() for each customer. I need to (cumulatively) sum them.

Could someone show me how to do this, please?




Customer:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Customer
{
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String address;
  private String phone;
  private String email;
  private ArrayList<Order> orders;

  public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String phone, String email)
  {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.address = address;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.email = email;
    orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
  }

  public int getTotalForAllOrders()
  {
    int total = 0;
    for (Order order : orders)
    {
      total += order.getTotal();
    }
    return total;
  }
}
```

Order:

```
public class Order
{
  private ArrayList<LineItem> lineItems;

  public Order()
  {
    lineItems = new ArrayList<LineItem>();
  }

  public int getTotal()
  {
    int total = 0;
    for (LineItem item : lineItems)
    {
      total += item.getSubTotal();
    }
    return total;
  }
}
```

Iterator:

```
public Iterator<Customer> getCustomerIterator()
{
    return customers.iterator();
}
```

Comment: If you have streams you can do `long sum = model.getCustomerStream().flatMapToLong(c -> c.stream().mapToLong(o -> o.getSubTotal()).sum();`

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your issue correctly, you just need to initialize sum outside of your while loop, you're just redeclaring the variable after the scope breaks.